# (Fe)Male Human vs Human (Fe)Male

Tags: questions

Why is it (fe)male human and not human (fe)male? Is it even correct to use second form?
I sometimes use the second form and was corrected yesterday but could not find anything about this topic.

Comment: Why is *what* that way?  You can find many examples of both ["human female"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22human+female%22) and ["female human"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22female+human%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsZ4BmcNdlgolOrXhnADF9eIdRIaeQ%3A1661771024011&ei=EJ0MY48G8qam1A_bsY34Ag&ved=0ahUKEwiPztW88-v5AhVyk4kEHdtYAy8Q4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%22female+human%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDoFCCEQqwI6BAgAEA1QsQZY6jZgjDloAHAAeACAAUyIAeAFkgECMTKYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books) in Google Books.

Answer (score 1):

You can say 'human male' or human female'. Who corrected you?

*Womanhood is the period in a human female's life after she has passed through childhood, puberty, and adolescence. (Wikipedia)*

*When a human female is born, it is almost invariably known that the baby is female, by inspection. (Philosophy paper)*

*THYMIDINE UPTAKE BY A RING X CHROMOSOME IN A HUMAN FEMALE. (Medical research paper)*

*a human female employed to do housework - crossword clue.*

Answer (score 1):

Whoever told you this is incorrect, although the confusion is understandable.

The confusion arises because 'male' and 'female' can be used as adjectives *or* nouns. But 'human' can also be either an adjective or a noun. As I'm sure you know, an adjective goes before the noun it describes. So, the determining factor is which word you ultimately want to use to define your subject. Do you want to say that they are human that happens to be male or a male that happens to be human?

You tend to see sex used as an adjective when speaking about animals, for example, '*a female dog*', '*a male baboon*' etc. This is mainly because 'dog', 'cat', 'monkey' etc can only be nouns. The equivalent words to 'human' that describe those species would be *canine*, *feline*, and *simian* respectively, and these can be either adjectives or nouns. Of course, you could say '*my dog is a female*', but in this example *both* are nouns, and you would be subcategorising your dog as both a dog *and* a female.

I would suggest that you hear 'human (fe)male' more than the other way around because we very rarely define ourselves as 'a human', probably because it goes without saying. Of course we are humans - what else could we be? We tend to use it as an adjective to emphasise our limitations (ie '*I'm only human*'). The nouns we use to refer to ourselves are usually 'man' and 'woman', and there would be no need to say either '*I'm a male man*', or even '*a human man*'.

Answer (score 0):

The form of phrase you have there is modifier-category. It is a question of which word is the modifier and which word is the category.

In your example, to some extent this is an option, and to some extent it is ambiguous. This is beause each of the words human and female can be either modifier or category. If one word were clearly a category and the other a modifier, it would be much more clear. For example, consider brown dog. It would be unusual to refer to a dog brown when you meant a dog that was brown. But in this case each word can be used as either a category or a modifier.

If the context tended to show one word or the other as a category,  you might put that one last. For example, if you were discussing sexual dimorphism in several different species, then the species might be the modifier and the sex the category. You might have human female, feline female, cetacean female, etc. "The feline female is nearly always secretive about giving birth. The cetacean female gives birth in open water and so is unable to be secretive."

However, it would be acceptable to change this order, particularly if you wanted to switch over to comparing male to female in one species. "The female feline is on average smaller than the male feline. This is in contrast to the female canadensis and male canadensis which are typically quite similar in size and appearance."

(Branta canadensis is the Canadian goose.)